# Visualize igraph degree distribution with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph

I want to visualise the degree distribution of an **igraph** object with **ggplot2**. Because **ggplot2** doesn't take a the simple numeric vector generated by `degree()` I convert it to a frequency table. Then I pass it to `ggplot()`. Still I get: `geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?` I can't set the table column `degree` to factors since I need to plot it also on a log scale.

```
library(igraph)
library(ggplot2)

g <- ba.game(20) 

degree <- degree(g, V(g), mode="in")
degree
# [1] 6 2 7 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

degree <- data.frame(table(degree))
degree
#   degree Freq
# 1      0   13
# 2      1    4
# 3      2    1
# 4      6    1
# 5      7    1

ggplot(degree, aes(x=degree, y=Freq)) +
  geom_line()
# geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have turned `degree$degree` into a factor by using `table`. Two things to fix this:

- make it a factor with all possible values (up to the largest degree) so that you don't miss the zeros.
- convert the labels back to numbers before plotting

Implementing those (I used `degree.df` instead of overwriting `degree` to keep the different steps distinct):

```
degree.df <- data.frame(table(degree=factor(degree, levels=seq_len(max(degree)))))
degree.df$degree <- as.numeric(as.character(degree.df$degree))
```

Then the plotting code is what you had:

```
ggplot(degree.df, aes(x=degree, y=Freq)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]